# Startup Tomcat: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Press Enter or Esc to exit

Tags: java, tomcat, installation, webserver, catalina

Using

I've installed Tomcat 8 (ignore the 10.1.7 that's on pic, once that's not compatible with Java 8) into my machine as Windows Service, when I startup, a new console is created with message:

[image]

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.   Press Enter or Esc to exit...
```

[image]
and `http://localhost:8080` returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Thanks in advance, you for your help.

Win 11, openjdk version "1.8.0_362", Tomcat 8
**strong text**
I was expecting `http://localhost:8080` to show Tomcat webpage running local

Comment: (1) What do you mean by setting environment variables? What environment variables did you set? (2) try to put tomcat to your user folder like your user folder `Downloads`

Comment: I've set the path to bin in Path env. var. but I've uninstalled and installed Tomcat 8 as windows service. Still getting some issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Install Tomcat 8 as Windows Service

## Install JDK 8

https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8

- Operating System: Windows
- Architecture: x64
- Package Type: JDK
- Version: 8
- .msi

click .msi

JDK Insatll Options: Please select

- Set JAVA_HOME variable
- JavaSoft(Oracle) registry keys

## Install Tomcat 8

https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

8.5.87 -> Binary Distributions -> Core: -> 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer

Download exe, Click ,run  install exe

Choose Components, options please select all items

- Tomcat -> core , **Service Startup** ,**Native**
- Start Menu Items
- Documentation
- Manager
- Host Manager
- Examples

Completing Apache Tomcat Setup

- Run Apache Tomcat
- Show Readme

Then open your browser http://localhost:8080

You don't need to set any environment variables, just follow the above steps and everything will be done.